# pass multiple Pandas dataframes to an executable via subprocess module in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, subprocess, executable

I have the following python script `example.py`, which I converted to a Windows Executable.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

def example(df1, df2):    

    print('Started the executable with example')
    df1 = pickle.loads(df1)
    df2 = pickle.loads(df2)

    print('df1 has {df1.shape[0]} rows')
    print('df2 has {df2.shape[0]} rows')

    return pickle.dumps(pd.concat([df1,df2]))

if __name__=="__main__":
example(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Then I use PyInstaller to create an executable named `example.exe` using `pyinstaller example.py -F`

Next, I have create random Pandas DataFrames in Python, let's call them `df1` and `df2`.

Now, I would like to use the `subprocess` module in the main Python script `main.py` to call this executable and get the results. This is the part with which I need help. Following is the code I wrote, but obviously isn't working.

```
import subprocess
import pickle
df_dump1 = pickle.dumps(df1)
df_dump2 = pickle.dumps(df2
command = ['./example.exe',df_dump1, df_dump2]
result = subprocess.run(command, 
                        input,=df_dump, 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell = True)
print(result.returncode, result.stdout, result.stderr)
```

The error message I get is this:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not \'str\`

Clearly, I am not able to send multiple Pandas dataframes (or even one) to the executable. Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using pickle.dump instead of pickle.dump**s**?

Comment: @above_c_level, that would require saving of the binary data as a file, and then be read by the executable, right? Would there be a way around it so that the data could be sent back and forth between the main Python code and the executable?

Comment: You could use [io.BytesIO()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) to save the serialized dataframe in a variable. But I would first check if dump works at all.